# Use of notes in ELU

Tags: support

I am quite new to this site and so far I am appreciating the help I receive . I have a question about the use of notes and I am sorry if I am asking something that  is taken for granted by more experienced users. I have noticed that often notes are used to give answers, instead of using the appropriate space for answers. I assume that a note is like a comment, an observation on a question or on another answer, but not an answer in itself. But often notes are used to provide full answers with appropriate links. Is this practice correct? Does it not reduce the ability for other users, especially the less experienced, to provide full answers? Thanks for you attention.

Comment: People are not supposed to (mis)use comments for answers (or vice versa). This is discouraged in a number of ways, e.g. there is no reputation for comments, and they can be deleted anytime without further notice. However, there are also a number of reasons why people go ahead and do it anyway, see the [linked question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/). Ultimately, it's up to the author.